# Error when running Corel PaintShop Photo Pro X3

Tags: paint-shop-pro

The program was OEM so I have no installation disc. Windows 7, 64-bit. When trying to run the program, I get the following error:

> The procedure entry point ?SetSmartCollectionFlag@COrganizerFuncs@@QAEX_N@Z could not be located in the dynamic link library CoreOrganizerr.dll

How can I get this program to open/run?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found the answer.  Go to the Corel website and download SP2 for Paintshop Photo Pro X3.  Run the program.  It worked like clockwork, so i also downloaded and installed SP3 and SP4.  Hope it works as well for you.

Answer (score 0):

Search your system for CoreOrganizer.dll.  Also search your system for regsvr32.exe.  When you find them both, drag CoreOrganizer.dll to the regsvr32.exe icon.  This will make your system attempt to register the dll.  With luck, this will fix the broken function reference.